# Report from Invoice template

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, report, invoice

I created an invoice template in the spreadsheet and used the attached VBA code to create  a report from it (essentially it stores certain cell values into another sheet as a tabular report).I would like to port this over to Google Spreadsheet and need help in converting the VBA to corresponding JavaScript. Can you help?

Thanks

```
Sub InvoiceReport()
    Dim myFile As String, lastRow As Long
    myFile = “C: \invoices\” & Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“B5”) & “_” & Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“F1”) & Format(Now(), “yyyy - mm - dd”) & “.pdf”
    lastRow = Sheets(“Sheet2”).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

    ‘ Transfer data to sheet2
    Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(lastRow, 1) = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“B5”)
    Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(lastRow, 2) = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“F1”)
    Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(lastRow, 3) = Sheets(“sheet1”).Range(“I36”)
    Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(lastRow, 4) = Now
    Sheets(“Sheet2”).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor: = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(lastRow, 5), Address: = myFile, TextToDisplay: = myFile‘ Create invoice in PDF format
    Sheets(“sheet1”).ExportAsFixedFormat Type: = xlTypePDF, Filename: = myFile
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ‘ create invoice in XLSX format
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs“ C: \invoices\” & Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“B5”) & “_” & Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“F1”) & “_” & Format(Now(), “yyyy - mm - dd”) & “.xlsx”, FileFormat: = 51‘ ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Saving the sheet as a PDF is one challenge, and copying the values over to another sheet is another. I would tackle these one at a time in two different questions, only after trying to figure it out on your own. There are many other answers on SO that relate to exporting a spreadsheet as a PDF.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I have updated my query to be more specific and with the code i am currently using. Hope this adds clarity.

Comment: one more thing, for the transfer can you share a spreadsheet with an example data set with what your expected output is? Makes it easier for whoever answers your question, so they don't have to start assuming what your data looks like.

Comment: Hi Douglas - i can share the sample invoice excel but not sure how to add an attachment to my post here (sorry my first post on this site). Can i email it?

Comment: Create an example google spreadsheet with the example data and share the link.

Comment: Try this. Sheet1 and Sheet 2 has needed sample data. Sheet 3 has additional info on mapping and VBA code i used in excel. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MLWllG7UZ2iBGkf8lShHk66P8tPSS3krIsS2KH6ohls/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hm, the invoice is not formatted in a way that would make it relatively easy to move around and modify with a script. It's still entirely possible, but would require a custom tailored solution. The easiest datasets to manipulate are plain tables.

Comment: I realize that but the template needs to maintain the formatting. Essentially, need to select specific cells from Sheet 1 (the cells would remain constant) and add values to the table in Sheet 2. Doable in Excel (with the attached VBA code). Was hoping the same logic recreated in JS would work with Google spreadsheet. Thanks.

Comment: It definitely can be recreated, in this case you would do the same thing in that you select each cell one by one, add those values to an object or an array. Then insert it into sheet2 as a row. Is `Buyer Name` the cell under `Bill To` on the invoice? I'm writing something up now, join the in-sheet chat if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, thankfully I've had to do this before.

This moves the data by getting the invoice information via a map that I made as an object so it's easily looped through. The tricky part was getting the PDF of the sheet.

I accomplished this by first scoping the function with `Driveapp.getRootFolder()` so I can get an oAuth token later. I utilized the `URLFetchApp` use the spreadsheets export functionality to retrieve a PDF blob. I then take this blob, name it, convert it to a file, and insert it into your drives root folder.

```js
//Data mapping for the invoice itself
var invoiceDetailsMap = {
  'Buyer Name': {
    rowIndex: 4,
    columnIndex: 1
  },
  'Invoice Number': {
    rowIndex: 0,
    columnIndex: 5    
  },
  'Total Amount': {
    rowIndex: 35,
    columnIndex: 7    
  },
  'Date & Time': {
    rowIndex: 0,
    columnIndex: 1    
  }   
}

//Entry point for script
function EntryPoint() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var valuesRange = dataRange.getValues();

  var invoiceData = GetInvoiceDetails(valuesRange);
  WriteInviceDetailsToSheet(invoiceData);
  GetPDF(spreadsheet, invoiceData['File Name']);
}

//Writes the invoice details to the 2nd sheet
function WriteInviceDetailsToSheet(invoiceData){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var valuesRange = dataRange.getValues();  
  var columns = GetColumns(valuesRange, dataRange.getNumColumns(), 0);

  var arrayToWrite = [[]];
  for(var column in columns.columns){
    if(typeof invoiceData[column] !== 'undefined'){
      arrayToWrite[0].push(invoiceData[column]);
    }
  }
  sheet.insertRowAfter(dataRange.getLastRow());
  sheet.getRange(dataRange.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, arrayToWrite[0].length).setValues(arrayToWrite);  
}

//Gets the invoice details absed on the mappings
function GetInvoiceDetails(valuesRange) {
  var output = {};
  for(var value in invoiceDetailsMap){
    output[value] = valuesRange[invoiceDetailsMap[value].rowIndex][invoiceDetailsMap[value].columnIndex];
  }
  output['File Name'] = 'Invoice' + output['Invoice Number'] + '_' + FormatDate(output['Date & Time'], 'MM.dd.yyyy');
  return output;
}

//Gets the PDF and inserts it into drive
function GetPDF(spreadsheet, fileName){
  DriveApp.getRootFolder(); //Scoping
  var urlParameters = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=letter&portrait=true&fitw=true&source=labnol&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false&gid=0';
  var baseURL = spreadsheet.getUrl();
  baseURL = baseURL.replace(/edit$/,'');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL + urlParameters, {
              headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
              });

  var pdfBlob = response.getBlob().setName(fileName + '.pdf');  
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);
  DriveApp.addFile(file);
}


//Reformts a date
function FormatDate(date, format)
{
  var temp = new Date(date);
  var output = Utilities.formatDate(temp, "PST", format);
  return output;
}

//Gets a columns object for the sheet for easy indexing
function GetColumns(valuesRange, columnCount, rowIndex)
{
  var columns = {
    columns: {},
    length: 0
  }

  Logger.log("Populating columns...");
  for(var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
  {
    if(valuesRange[0][i] !== ''){
      columns.columns[valuesRange[0][i]] = {index: i ,value: valuesRange[0][i]};
      columns.length++;      
    }
  }  
  return columns;
}
```